# How to start testing Zend Framework Models?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-test

How do I begin testing my models in a Zend Framework 1.8+ application?

Let's say I have my application set up to start testing. I have already tested a controller, so I know it works. I have all my controllers extending my `ControllerTestCase.php` file:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

abstract class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public $application;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );

        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap()
    {
        $this->application->bootstrap();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->resetInstance();

        $this->resetRequest();
        $this->resetResponse();

        $this->request->setPost(array());
        $this->request->setQuery(array());
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

But now I want to start testing my models. It seems like my `ModelTestCase.php` would not extend `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase` but rather a `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ModelTestCase`, but no such class exists that I know of. How can I start testing my Zend Framework models?

Answer (score 7):

There is a base `ControllerTestCase` provided for you because there are complex steps needed to setup and tear down the environment for testing a controller.  The input is a mock HTTP request, and the output is rendered HTML that you need to scrape to find expected content.

A Model is more like a plain old PHP object.  There's less environment to set up.  The interface is simply method calls to the object.

So I would start a `TestCase` class that extends PHPUnit's plain `TestCase`, and start by adding at least one `test` method (as an **empty function**) for each method in your Model class.  You will eventually have many test methods for each method in your Model class, but creating the empty test methods is a good way to keep from forgetting some of your Model methods.

Note that [a Model is not a Table](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2008/05/activerecord-does-not-suck.html) -- a Model typically *uses* one or more Table objects.  By following this pattern, you have the opportunity to create [mock objects](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects) for Tables so you can run the test suite without requiring a live connection to a database.

Here's an example of setting up a mock Table object, which is hardcoded to return a synthetic data set instead of a data set from a database.

```
<?php

class MyModelTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  protected $_model;

  public function setUp()
  {
    $foo = $this->getMock('FooTable', array('find'));
    $foo->expects($this->any())
        ->method('find')
        ->will($this->returnValue(array("id"=>"123")));

    $this->_model = new MyModel();
    $this->_model->setFooTable($foo);
  }

  public function testCountElements()
  {
    $this->_model->get(123);
    $n = $this->_model->countElements();
    $this->assertEquals(1, $n);
  }

  public function testAsArray()
  {
    $this->_model->get(123);
    $a = $this->_model->asArray();
    $this->assertType('array', $a);
  }

  public function testAddElement()
  {
    // ...etc.
  }

  public function testGetElement()
  {
    // ...etc.
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a very good explanation. I was wondering if you would mind including a little more about including/requiring/autoloading models when you are testing. I have a model that extends an abstract model. Maybe this is where mock objects come in?

Comment: I've added some detail above showing the use of a mock Table object.  Loading the classes is totally ordinary, you can do it with `require_once` or with autoloading.  I think you might be making this more complex than it actually is.